# How to dynamically call an ActionResult in your API by using an Ajax-call?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, api, model-view-controller

I have coded in the StartUp.cs the following code for calling my API.

```
            services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", c =>
            {
#if DEBUG
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:12345");
#else
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myApi.com");
#endif
```

But when I want to call the ActionResult by using an Ajax-call, he can't find the API.

```
    alert(apiUrl);

    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl + '/MyApiProcesses/GetSomething',
        type: 'POST',
```

So I have written this variable in a js-file.

```
var apiUrl = 'https://localhost:12345';
//var apiUrl = 'https://myApi.com';
```

I want to know if it is possible to write it dynamically. If you declare it in the startup, you don't have to declare it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use urls in ajax or httpclient, I usually do it this way, but it takes several steps to get a string from appsettings.

1. Create AppUrl section in appsettings.json

```
"AppUrl": {
    "DevUrl": "http//..",
    "ProductUrl": "http//..",
     .... another urls if needed
   
},
```

2.Create class for this section

```
 public class AppUrlSettings
  {
        public string DevUrl{ get; set; }
        public string ProdUrl{ get; set; }

        ....another urls
   }
```

3. configure settings in startup

```
var appUrlSection=Configuration.GetSection("AppUrl");

services.Configure<AppUrlSettings>(appUrlSection);

var urls = appUrlSection.Get<AppUrlSettings>();

services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", c =>
 {
#if DEBUG
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(urls.DevUrl);
#else
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri(urls.ProdUrl;
#endif
});
```

4. now you can use them like this

```
public class MyController:Controller
    {
        private readonly IOptions<AppUrlSettings> _appUrls;

        public MyController (IOptions<AppUrlSettings> appUrls)
        {
            _appUrls = appUrls;
        }

        public  IActionResult MyAction()
        {
           var model= new Model
           {
            DevUrl=_appUrls.Value.DevUrl;
               ...
           }
        }
}
```

you can then use urls as hidden fields.

or you can get urls from model in javascript directly:

```
var devUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.DevUrl));
.....
```

Or  if you need the urls in many places, it  can  make sense to create a special service that you can inject directly in the views you need

Comment: Thank you it works fine.